# getCurrentLocale возвращает неправильную локаль

Tags: php, laravel, маршрутизация, locale

Всем привет,

Подскажите в Laravel 5.5 c Twig-темплейтами я использую https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization 
для локалазации
И на урл http://127.0.0.1:8000/ru/tmp_csvp/index

```
echo '<pre>$::'.print_r(with ( new LaravelLocalization)->getCurrentLocale(),true).'</pre>';
```

возвращает "en", возможно из-за того что я использую

```
(new LaravelLocalization)
```

?

Но на строку 
echo '

```
++
```

```
LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale()::'.print_r(LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale(),true).'</pre>';
```

Получаю ошибку :

```
Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale() should not be called statically
```

В routes/web.php:

```
Route::group(
    [
        'prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(),
        'middleware' => [ 'localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect', 'localeViewPath' ]
    ],

    function()
{

    Route::get('/tmp_csvp/{route_url?}', 'TmpCsvpController@index')->where('route_url','[index|list|listing]+' );
    Route::post('/tmp_csvp/{route_url?}', 'TmpCsvpController@index')->where('route_url','[index|list|listing]+');

});
```

В app/Http/Kernel.php :

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,

    'localize' => \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LaravelLocalizationRoutes::class,
    'localizationRedirect' => \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LaravelLocalizationRedirectFilter::class,
    'localeSessionRedirect' => \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LocaleSessionRedirect::class,
    'localeViewPath' => \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LaravelLocalizationViewPath::class

];
```

Как правильно ?

Dmytro K,
Я не уверен что правильно понял.
Делаю:
1) В добавил app/Http/Kernel.php :

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
        \App\Http\Middleware\LocalizeApiRequests::class,
    ],

    'locale' => [ // Группа которую я добавил
        'localize' => \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LaravelLocalizationRoutes::class,
        'localizationRedirect' => \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LaravelLocalizationRedirectFilter::class,
        'localeSessionRedirect' => \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LocaleSessionRedirect::class,
        'localeViewPath' => \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware\LaravelLocalizationViewPath::class

    ],
];
```

2) В routes/web.php:

```
Route::group(
    [                                          
        'prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(),
        'middleware' => [ 'localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect', 'localeViewPath', 'locale' ] //Добавил locale ???!!!
    ],

    function()
{
    /** ADD ALL LOCALIZED ROUTES INSIDE THIS GROUP **/
    Route::get('/tmp_csvp/edit/{id}', 'TmpCsvpController@edit');
    Route::post('/tmp_csvp/edit/{id}', 'TmpCsvpController@update');

    Route::get('/tmp_csvp/{route_url?}', 'TmpCsvpController@index')->where('route_url','[index|list|listing]+' );
    Route::post('/tmp_csvp/{route_url?}', 'TmpCsvpController@index')->where('route_url','[index|list|listing]+');
    Route::get('/tmp_csvp/destroy', 'TmpCsvpController@destroy');

    Route::get('/dashboard/msg', 'DashboardController@msg');
    Route::get('/dashboard/{route_url?}', 'DashboardController@index')->where('route_url','[index]+' );;
    Route::post('/dashboard/{route_url?}', 'DashboardController@index')->where('route_url','[index]+' );;

});
```

Но не помогло и все равно на урле

`http://local-csvp.com/ru/tmp_csvp


( new LaravelLocalization)->getCurrentLocale()`

- возвращает “en”

Что неправильно ?

Comment: в middleware  есть метод, который ставит локализацию по url?

Comment: Классы 'localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect', 'localeViewPath' определены в app/Http/Kernel.php как и описано в доке.
Или их еще где-то еще нужно прописать ?

Comment: В моем app/Http/Middleware/ подкаталоге есть 5 php-файлов.
Мне нужно прописать классы  'localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect', 'localeViewPath' в один из этих файлов или создать новый?

Comment: если в Kernel.php прописаны - то все верно. Но нужно еще эту группу middleware добавить или в роуте, или в конструктор контроллера. Я бы создал в роуте группу, в нее засунул бы middleware и в этой группе прописывал бы все роуты

Comment: В первоначальном посте я     написал содержимое routes/web.php:    'middleware' => [ 'localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect', 'localeViewPath' ] . разве не это ?

Comment: в Kernel.php есть  protected $middlewareGroups = [  ]; Создайте еще одну группу, locale например, запихните туда все свои middleware, а группу прописать в роутах